# Autocad 2017 Extract Xdata excel lisp

Tags: excel, metadata, autocad, extract, autolisp

I know there must be a way to extract custom Xdata from an Autocad drawing.

Could somebody please point me in the right direction of where to search?

I'm looking for a method or AutoLISP that will collect/extract the custom added, Xdata
from a bunch of polylines. These polylines will have the following custom Xdata;

- Name
- Number
- Area (given that they are closed)

The standard 'Extract Data' method in Autocad does not extract any name or another reference to the extracted data. So there is no way telling which data is from which polyline.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain xdata associated with a particular Application ID or multiple Application IDs, simply supply the [entget](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-12540DAE-C84B-4BDB-AEEC-DDFE5BE3C42A) function with the optional `applist` argument following the entity name argument.

This argument is a list of Application IDs for which to return xdata (if present in the DXF data associated with the supplied entity).

For example, if your Application ID is `"MyAppID"`, you would evaluate the `entget` function in the following manner:

```
(entget <entity-name> '("MYAPPID"))
```

(Note that I have supplied a quoted literal list in this example - for more information on this convention, refer to [my tutorial](http://lee-mac.com/quote.html) on the subject).

To help you to inspect all DXF data (including xdata) associated with a particular entity, I have developed an [Entity List](http://lee-mac.com/entitylist.html) program.

On selecting a polyline from your drawing using this program or by evaluating `entget` with an application list argument of `("MYAPPID")`, you may obtain a DXF data such as:

```
(
    (-1 . <Entity name: 7ffff706880>)  ;; Pointer to self
    (0 . "LWPOLYLINE")                 ;; Entity Type
    (330 . <Entity name: 7ffff7039f0>) ;; Point to parent
    (5 . "FFF")                        ;; Handle
    (100 . "AcDbEntity")               ;; Class
    (67 . 0)                           ;; Tilemode
    (410 . "Model")                    ;; Layout
    (8 . "0")                          ;; Layer
    (100 . "AcDbPolyline")             ;; Subclass
    (90 . 4)                           ;; Vertices
    (70 . 1)                           ;; Bitwise flag (1=Closed)
    (43 . 0.0)                         ;; Constant width
    (38 . 0.0)                         ;; Elevation
    (39 . 0.0)                         ;; Thickness
    (10 18.9133 17.6315)               ;; Vertex coordinate (OCS)

    < ... additional vertex data ... >

    (10 18.9133 12.7863)               ;; Vertex coordinate (OCS)
    (40 . 0.0)                         ;; Segment starting width
    (41 . 0.0)                         ;; Segment ending width
    (42 . 0.0)                         ;; Segment bulge
    (91 . 0)                           ;; Vertex identifier
    (210 0.0 0.0 1.0)                  ;; Extrusion (normal) vector

    ;; xData starts here:
    (-3
        (
            "MYAPPID"                  ;; Application ID
            (1002 . "{")               ;; Data grouping opening brace
            (1040 . 1.2345)            ;; Real-valued (Double) data (your area value)
            (1070 . 123)               ;; Int-valued data (your polyline number)
            (1000 . "MyPolyline")      ;; String-valued data (your polyline name)
            (1002 . "}")               ;; Data grouping closing brace
        )
    )
)
```

Therefore, the list of xdata may be accessed by acquiring DXF group -3 from this list:

```
(assoc -3 (entget <entity-name> '("MYAPPID")))
```

Which will return:

```
(-3
    (
        "MYAPPID"                  ;; Application ID
        (1002 . "{")               ;; Data grouping opening brace
        (1040 . 1.2345)            ;; Real-valued (Double) data (your area value)
        (1070 . 123)               ;; Int-valued data (your polyline number)
        (1000 . "MyPolyline")      ;; String-valued data (your polyline name)
        (1002 . "}")               ;; Data grouping closing brace
    )
)
```

If you are querying more than one Application ID, you may then acquire the data associated with your target Application ID using:

```
(cdr (assoc "MYAPPID" (cdr (assoc -3 (entget <entity-name> '("MYAPPID"))))))
```

Or, if you are only returning the xdata associated with one Application ID, you could simply use:

```
(cdadr (assoc -3 (entget <entity-name> '("MYAPPID"))))
```

Here, `cdadr` is a contraction of `(cdr (car (cdr)))`.

This will then return:

```
(
    (1002 . "{")               ;; Data grouping opening brace
    (1040 . 1.2345)            ;; Real-valued (Double) data (your area value)
    (1070 . 123)               ;; Int-valued data (your polyline number)
    (1000 . "MyPolyline")      ;; String-valued data (your polyline name)
    (1002 . "}")               ;; Data grouping closing brace
)
```

From which you may retrieve the relevant values either using `assoc` if the group codes are unique, or iterate over the list and rely on the association pair positioning.

Here is a test program for you to try:

```
(defun c:test ( / ent )
    (if (setq ent (car (entsel)))
        (print (cdadr (assoc -3 (entget ent '("MYAPPID")))))
    )
    (princ)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get XData from the entity by LISP is:

```
(assoc -3 (entget entity (list "*")))
```

Example code will ask You to select the entity and will display its XData.

```
(assoc -3 (entget (car(entsel )) (list "*")))
```

Now You need to decide what to do with this informations. 
For example, You can save it to CSV file where each row will be one entity, and in the first column write object Handle (to get the connection between entity and data) then extracted data.